# upload a file from a web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently developing a web application. Using this web application I want to be able to upload a file from my desktop to the server. The uploaded file should change every time I upload it.

**What I already tried:**

I tried adding it to my project but unfortunately when I uploaded the file it didn't overwrite the old one.

---

My other problem is when I write the path of the file I want to upload into the `<a> </a>` tags the file doesn't uploads from the navigator.

I've already tried this :

```html
<a href="file:///E:/hps/template_bank_modified.sql"> upload the file <a/>.
```

Comment: See this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_fileupload_get You are using a wrong tag.

Comment: Files can only be uploaded via drag and drop or `<input type="file">`

Comment: it's not what i really want to do . actually i don't want to choose the file from the desktop  like you've done i want it to be automatically ,  like the file should be uploaded when i click on the button

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a web application to retrieve files from the local file system. That would be a major security violation. This requires user interaction where the user must manually select the file to be uploaded every single time.

Comment: so my main use of my application it that a user complete a form and the application modified a file with this data and return the file to the user i order to upload it  is there any method to do it , namely to upload it

Comment: You need to use an input element something like this: `<input type="file" name="fileupload">` Then the user will be able to select a file from somewhere in the operating system. But it's a process the user must control entirely for security reasons.

Comment: the file must go from the application to the user not the other way

Comment: In that case, the user must click on something to download and save the file. So you can present a link to the file, a button, etc. But you can't automatically just force a download. Again, that would be another security violation.

Comment: that's what i've tried to do but which link can i used for exemple